# Libgdx - how to properly dispose sound files

Tags: libgdx

When should a sound effect be disposed of?

I'm a bit confused about sound effects vs music.  With music, I just dispose of it when a level is complete as I have the music just repeat until the end of the level and then that music is no longer used.  With sound effects, they play for a short time so I'm not sure what happens when one is done and a new one plays of the same sound.

For example, the player character can shoot a gun and each time the shoot sound plays.  So if the player shoots 6 times, is that sound effect handled like 6 separate sounds which need to be disposed of or is a sound file only to be disposed of once when no longer needed regardless of how many times it is used?

Comment: what do you mean by 6 separate sounds ? Is it 6 different sound file's `Sound` like `x1.mp3`, `x2.mp3`, `x3.mp3`... ?

Comment: I was using an example of one sound file being played 6 times.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to dispose of it each time it's played. Just dispose it when you dispose your other game assets (ie call it from the Game dispose method when the game is being disposed).

When the player shoots 6 times, the sound will be played 6 times concurrently.
From the javadoc:

> Plays the sound. If the sound is already playing, it will be played again, concurrently.

But there aren't 6 different sounds you should be disposing or anything like that.

So to answer your question: *is a sound file only to be disposed of once when no longer needed regardless of how many times it is used?*

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

**For Small Projects/Games :**

1. Any Sound that you're using on PlayScreen, create once in Game's `create()` method and use inside your game not dispose them.

   ```
   Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/mysound.mp3"));
   ```

   Dispose sound in `dispose()` method of `ApplicationListener`, that is called when you exit your Game.
2. Create your Sound in `show()` method of Screen Interface, and dispose them in `dispose()` of Screen but `dispose()` of Screen is not called by framework so you need to call by yourself so call dispose() method from `hide()` method of Screen.
3. Use AssetManager and manage your resource by loading ,unloading by your requirement and dispose your `AssetManager` in dispose in ApplicationListener.

**For Big Porjects/Game in Resource wise**

You must use AssetManager because you've to manage lot's of resources.

Comment: I have a specific assets class where I have my AssetManager and everything related to sounds, music and textures. I create a static object of that class in my Game's create() and when the game runs the pause(), I call the assets class dispose().  I had an issue with home key being pressed and the textures disappearing when the game reloaded so now I dispose of the textures when pause() is called and reload the textures when the game reloads.  Still have an increase in memory use from home/reload, but I'm not certain it's related to this.  Still working on it.

Comment: The memory increase issue is why I asked this question about the sound effects as I only dispose of them one time and I just didn't know if I was doing that wrong and that could be contributing to my other issue.

Comment: @ace106 I don't think so you've memory issue, If you're creating once and disposing at last/end of the game.